# How can I restrict the acces to some folders on a shared PC

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I've got a PC of which I'm admin. But also other people can access it as admin.

The PC is on a Domain of which I'm **not** the admin.

**I want to encrypt some folder or all the hard drive.**

How can I achieve this result?

The solution should work on domain and be able to protect my data from the other PC admin / Domain admin / PC Owner.

OS: Windows 7

Comment: You could for example start by mentioning which operating system you are trying to achieve this on. You could also try to use your favourite Search Engine to search for information on Truecrypt and bathe in the plethora of results it will give you.

Comment: Just a thought/warning: If I, as a domain admin, found an encrypted TrueCrypt (or alike) container on my network domain that I didn't have access to, it'd be locked away from everyone until the owner was found and questioned, or just deleted outright.  And that's how the CEO would expect me to react.  So you better have the Domain Admin's blessing before you do trying this or your stuff may just vanish unexpectedly.

Comment: @techie007: it's a matter of culture. Also slavery could be acceptable for some guys. American have just one 1 week of holiday and they think it's good and normal. In the USA also there was no national insurance. If I have got a laptop and I can install dropbox on it and also skype I would like to crypt all this personal information. And spying this kind of data is a crime in most of states. But when you get fired they could pretend you to leave without deleting personal data, so I prefer to crypt my personal data. The ideal should be people making law to restrict company to behave well...

Comment: If you are storing it on their network it may be deleted by them.  It has nothing to do with opening it, or spying on anyone.  It definitely has nothing to do with nationality or slavery. :/  I'm going by the assumption that it's your work or school's network/domain in question, if it's not, and you're paying for the space, that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to encrypt existing files (in-place encrypting) you cannot use native NTFS EFS encryption because the encryption keys are always accessible by the domain administrator (and therefore will be able to decrypt)

if you are willing to start a new encryption process (copy everything over from existing folder to new encrypted destination) and feel adventurous, there is a project called encfs which has recently got a windows [port](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html).
it is experimental and also at the bottom of the project port page there is a link to an experimental [GUI](https://docs.google.com/folderview?usp=sharing&id=0B1bZKx3uhkruYmVadXBSNUZNS2c) for it.

Also a more stable solution was already mentioned, TrueCrypt

Microsoft released also a software called Microsoft Private Folder but it is no longer available for download on their website. Yuo can find though a copy on SoftPedia http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Lockdown/Microsoft-Private-Folder.shtml

Comment: Which one do you advice me?

Comment: depends. you want something simple where you have only a private folder then MPF is the easiest, but you're out of support (if you run into issues nobody is going to be able to help). you want stability and a large community - go with truecrypt. you want to tryout something new and help it grow, go with encfs port (with or without the gui). just keep in mind that encryption is not backup - don't rely solely on encryption to protect your data.

Comment: I'm trying truecrypt. But I've got some problems with skype since I have to move cronology to the mounted partition..

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt a folder in Windows you can:

```
Right-click the folder or file you want to encrypt, and then click Properties.

Click the General tab, and then click Advanced.

Select Encrypt contents to secure data box, click OK, and then click OK again.
```

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7)

If you also wish to password protect a folder on top of this you can always have a look a [True Crypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) which has worked perfectly well for me. A guide to doing this can be found  [here](http://notebooks.com/2010/07/03/how-to-create-encrypted-folder-using-truecrypt/)

Comment: Does it work on domain? The other PC admin / Domain admin can access the same data?

Comment: They can only if you want them to. If you give them the password.